# Задачи на микросервисы grpc

Tags: grpc

Приступил к изучению grpc
Подкиньте пожалуйста задач. Написание каких сервисов поможет более детально разобрать этот протокол и набить руку в микросервисах?
Хочу написать разных сервисов и объединить в одну программу, возможно даже на разных языках.
Благодарю)

Comment: создать 2 сервиса. 
один посылает скорость и время.
а другой в ответ дает расстояние.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Накидал кода. [здесь](https://github.com/udonetsm/distance)
А если повысить сложность?

Comment: сервис 1 непрерывно шлет скорость и время с промежутком N секунд (0.5 секунд, например)

сервис 2 непрерывно слушает и выводит текущее ускорение. 

ключевой момент непрерывно ))

Comment: @SeniorPomidor это  мои недочеты или новое задание?

Comment: это как продолжение старой задачи. можете считать ее как новую задачу.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Спасибо. Буду разибраться))

Comment: @SeniorPomidor ладно, задам этот вопрос...
а разве net.Listen не непрерывно слушает?

Comment: возможно, вы меня поняли неправильно. непрерывно имеется в виду что оба сервиса не перестают работать после ввода данных. не так как сделан speedandtime/SaT.go. вам же нужно набор данных передать.  
просто берете и читайте файл  -> отправляете в другой сервис

Comment: @SeniorPomidor получается нужно придумать другой способ передачи скорости и времени, чтобы после получения расстояния, можно было внести данные снова? Правильно понял? Типа цикличность?

Comment: можно и так понимать. делайте как вам легче, но каждую секунду вводить данные вручную вы устанете. поэтому предложил читать файл

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131121/discussion-between-umd-and-senior-pomidor).